# Correct process step by step to forecast time series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have to work with 1000 time series of food retail products (with weekly data).
Each of these time series corresponds to the sales of each product.
I need to obtain forecasts for each of these time series and I would like to know if I'm doing this in a right way.

**STEP 1: Data Adjustment**
With the `group_by` function (`dplyr` package), for each product/time series I add missing values for the weeks that don't exist yet and I put zero values for the sales in that new dates that I've just created. For the other variables, like prices, I rolling the values with `na.locf` function to avoid NA's value in the new added dates.
My goal is to clean every time series from trash data and obtain time series with no NA's weekly observations from 2014 to today.

**STEP 2: Splitting Time Series**
With the `group_by` function, for each product/time series I divide my sample of data in 2 groups: Training Set (80%) and Test Set (20%).
My goal is to find the best model possible that fit the time serie of the Training Set and then use that best model to produce forecast for the remaining Test Set. In this way I can compare, even with a plot, the forecasts with the real data of the Test Set.

**STEP 3: Creation of time series object and some subset of regressors**
With the `group_by` function, for each product/time series I create the time serie (with the `ts` function) for the Training Set, then I create some subset of regressors. I do this because I preliminarily don't know which is the best subset of regressors that I have to use to fit a model to my time series.
For example, one subset of regressors could be formed by two variables, another subset of regressors could be formed by only one other variable etc...

**STEP 4: Fit a linear model for all the subset of regressors that I've just created**
With the function `lm` I try to find what is the relation between my dependent variable (that I need to forecast) and all the subset of regressors that I've created before.
I don't know if it's correct to use `lm`, maybe someone could help me with this issue :)

**STEP 5: Evaluating the best model according to step 4 (`AIC`,`BIC`, `R^2 adj`)**
With the function `CV` I can obtain the indexes (`AIC`, `BIC`, `R^2 adj`, etc) that I need to evaluate which is the best subset that I will have to use in the next steps to fit in the best way possible a model to my time series.
For now, I choose that the best subset of regressors is that with the minimum value of `AIC`, but it's only my initial choice.

**STEP 6: Trasformation in log(x+1) (because of zero's values in time series)**
With the `group_by` function, for each product/time series I transform the time serie of the Training Set in log(ts +1). In that way, I can calculate the logarithm for each observation of my time series, even for that observation where I put zero at STEP 1. (Someone can say if it is mathematically correct?)
N.B. I transform only the time series of my dependent variable, not the regressors; it could be a problem?

**STEP 7: Handling outliers**
With the `group_by` function, for each product/time series I use the `tso` function (`tsoutliers` package) to find if there are outliers and, if yes, to manage that values.
It is necessary to obtain reliable forecasts in the next steps.

**STEP 8:Fit auto.arima model with xreg = best subset of regressor find in STEP 5**
With the `group_by` function, for each product/time series of the Training Set I use the `auto.arima` function (forecast package) with the `xreg` parameter;  then, if it's not possible, I use the simple `ets` function with no regressors (especially in these case where the time series is too short, is it correct? Often, if I don't use the ets model the error NO SUITABLE ARIMA MODEL FOUND comes and I don't know why).
Then, with the forecast function with `xreg`= best subset of regressors (same length of the Test Set) I obtain my forecasts for the Test Set period.

**STEP 9: Back transformation from log to original scale**
With the `group_by` function, for each product/time series I re-transform in the original scale the forecasts obtained and I plot these values with the real data of the Test Set.

**STEP 10: Evaluate accuracy of the forecasts**
With the function `accuracy` (`forecast` package) I obtain some indexes, like `MASE`, `MAPE`, `MAE` etc; considering that my time series have all the same scale, I think that it is good to use the `MAE` as the index of the accuracy, is it true?

Someone can help me with this work?
Is it all right what I've just wrote o am I missing something very important? What do you think?
My steps are correct? Someone would add something else?

Thanks in advance guys!